# Hibernate stats, method name

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss

I added to jboss (info about hibernate statistics):

```
<system-properties>
   <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
</system-properties>


  <logger category="org.hibernate.stat">
     <level name="DEBUG"/>
  </logger>
```

output from log:

```
16:39:33,648 DEBUG [org.hibernate.stat.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) [rid:1506251439320100001] HHH000117: HQL: select .... time: 364ms, rows: 6023 
16:39:33,741 DEBUG [org.hibernate.stat.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) [rid:1506251439320100001] HHH000117: HQL: select ...., time: 1ms, rows: 5
```

Exist any possibility to add to this log, information about method (which contains this sql query) ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

However, you could add interceptors or aspects to your DAO classes and log your own statistics there. [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) is the documentation on how to do it in Spring for example.